# Change advisors?

Tags: graduate-school, advisor

My advisor is changing institutions, and I am at the end of my 4th year in a computational biology program and have passed through all my formal requirements. I have no publications due to the nature of my project.

What would it mean to change advisors at this point. I have been supported by my fellowship ever since I joined this lab (three years), but my funding will be over starting this upcoming academic year. Either my current advisor or advisor I switch to will have to support me with their funding.

Comment: How are *we* supposed to answer this question? Obviously we can't make a decision for you, and we know less about your particular situation than *you* do - so what do you want us to tell you that you don't already know?

Comment: A more specific/suitable question would be: What a change of advisors would mean at this point of the phd? Is this related to what you want to know?

Comment: _Is it worth it?_ is really up to you. Please clarify why you used your own fund up to now? Who is supporting you? Are you looking for funding at this time?

Comment: please see changes above

Answer (score 4):

One important piece of information you give here is that you do not have any publications. I can't comment precisely about the field of computational biology, but in many fields (e.g. engineering, CS...) this will adversely affect your prospects for an academic position after you finish your PhD. I would say that you should make publishing a priority, and decide accordingly.

If you are close to getting results from your current project with your advisor, you could consider continuing. If the project is a true dead-end, you could consider making changes; but another option could be to finish as soon as possible and try to somehow find a post-doc position in a setting where you can be more productive.

Comment: Without publications it is rather difficult to find a post-doc without the word of your supervisor/professors.

Comment: @MikeyMike - true; hence, "somehow."